# Sending a sequence of key strokes with nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

i want to send the sequence of key strokes **Ctrl + Alt + p**

i tried that but it doesn't work : .keys(['U+E009','U+E00A', 'p'])

```
module.exports = {
  'Test' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:3000')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .keys(['U+E009','U+E00A', 'p'])

        (...)

      .end();
  }
};
```

someone have an idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code: .keys(['U+E009','U+E00A', 'p'])

with this:         .keys(["\uE009", "\uE00A", "P"])

and see if you are able to resolve the issue. For me, issue is resolved after doing this change.